# Full node getting stuck

Tags: iri-node, stuck

Since yesterday evening, my full node has been stuck at 3532941 total transactions.

> 12/03 11:59:12.426 [pool-2-thread-2] INFO  com.iota.iri.network.Node - toProcess = 1000 , toBroadcast = 0 , toRequest = 1 , toReply = 2 / totalTransactions = 3532941

Latest milestone index was also out-dated at 294393.

Restarting the node solved the problem, but then after some time it got stucked again.

Any idea why this happens? Any idea about how to solve this problem?