# What can be the reason for the Solid Milestone Index not to increase overtime?

Tags: iri-node, milestones

I have a node that always worked. When I do something like updating iri, for example, everything seems fine with it.

The problem is, in these cases, the "Solid Milestone Index" started to increase for a few milestones and now it's stuck in a certain index number (308077 this time).

What is the problem and how can I solve it?

Comment: I think you must be patient. I had it lag behind for about 15 minutes, then suddenly it was the same.

Comment: @DanielF mine is stuck for hours..

Comment: How many really active neighbors do you have?

Comment: you can also check in #botbox on slack whether the coordinator is having any issues (otherwise it should post there every minute)

Comment: Related? https://iota.stackexchange.com/questions/449/full-node-getting-stuck

Answer (score 1):

Two possibilities (but there may be others):

- your neighbors are dead or not synchronized. In this case your node cannot synchronize with the Tangle. solution: find other neighbor. You may consider using Nelson to improve your connectivity to the network (check channel #nelson on the slack)
- you run into a behavior that is suspected to be a bug in IRI https://github.com/iotaledger/iri/issues/428. solution: restart your node

Comment: Please add some explanations to these possibilities, maybe some indication to find out which is the culprit. Otherwise this is more a comment than an answer.

Comment: Thank you for pointing out the inadequacy of my response, I have added some clarifications. This said, I can't comment other people posts at the moment because I don't have enough reputation.